# How can I hold a WPF storyboard animation for a second, before continuing?

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard, timing

We have a color animation that blends from red to white.  Currently, this is a linear fade.  We know we can play with the `Storyboard` class's BeginTime and such, but that simply delays the start of the entire animation.  We've also looked at the ease-in/ease-out side of things, but they don't seem to work either.

Specifically, we'd like to hold a value of red for one second, then fade from red to white over the next.  Can that be done in pure XAML?  If not, can it be done in code-behind manually setting up a storyboard? ...or do we have to use two separate storyboards and play them in sequence?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Several ways to do this.

**with key frames:**

```
<Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color">
        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="Red" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="Red" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
        <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="White" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

**with two animations in sequence:**

```
<Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                    From="Red" To="Red" Duration="0:0:1" />
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                    To="White" BeginTime="0:0:1" Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
```

**with a custom easing function:**

```
<Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                    From="Red" To="White" Duration="0:0:2">
        <ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
            <local:CustomEasingFunction />
        </ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
    </ColorAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

In this case a function that shows the transition in the first half of duration and holds the value in the second half. Because the default EasingMode is EaseOut this function will then 'play' backwards.

```
public class CustomEasingFunction : EasingFunctionBase
{
    public CustomEasingFunction() : base()
    { }

    protected override double EaseInCore(double normalizedTime)
    {
        return (normalizedTime < 0.5)
            ? normalizedTime * 2
            : 1;
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new CustomEasingFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very thorough and exactly what I needed.  This is a great S.O. answer too as I know others will be happy with the level of detail you've provided.  Thanks so much!

Comment: One question though... are you sure about your comment in the Easing Function example?  According to MSDN, the normalized time goes from 0 to 1, not 1 to 0 as you stated, thus the return value should be 0 for values less than 0.5 (the first half of the duration), then be '(normalizedTime * 2) - 1' (which is the same as '(normalizedTime - 0.5) * 2') for the second half, correct?  I got that from here... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.easingfunctionbase.easeincore.aspx

Comment: Aaah!  I figured out why you though it went from 1 to 0.  You have the EasingMode set to the default which is EaseOut, which states that the values returned from 'Ease' should be 100% interpolation minus the result of the EaseInCore function, hence you thinking it went from 1 to 0.  A double-negative if you will.  However, because the function is called EaseInCore, for consistency it should probably be written with the time going from 0 to 1, then EasingMode would have to be explicitly set to EaseIn, but again, that would be clearer since the function would represent time elapsed correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I already wondered about this as I started the creation. Thanks again.

Comment: No prob.  That's what this site is for.  We help each other! ...like how you're gonna help me by voting my comment up, right? [smirk]

Comment: After further thinking about this I've edited my answer to add your discovery. I think now it's still simple but consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you have your animations written, you could just add a transition "from" Red "to" Red that takes a second at the beginning. So technically the animation is running, but its not doing anything. That can be done in pure XAML.